# How to rotate an object back and forth around a specific point?

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael, transform

I'm using Raphael JS in an attempt to rotate an image shape around a point which is below its center point. How can this be done?

I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
var playBBox = playButtonRef.getBBox();
var xPos = playBBox.x + playBBox.width/2;
var yPos = playBBox.y;
var animObject = Raphael.animation({
    transform: playButtonRef.attr("transform") + "R60," + (this.cx - 25) + "," + this.cy
}, 3000);​
animObject = animObject.repeat(10); 
playButtonRef.animate(animObject);
```

I'm also looking for a way to rotate it back to its original position. how to I make it trace its path back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. to rotate around the specified points, you may use the `xPos` and `yPos` you've already defined, and modify them to reference a point below the center by increasing the Y value.
2. to trace its path back, you can use the `callback` param to invoke an additional animation call which will reset the shape to its original position.

here's how to make it work:

```
var playBBox = playButtonRef.getBBox();
var xPos = playBBox.x + (playBBox.width / 2);
var yPos = playBBox.y + 25;

var animObject = Raphael.animation({
    transform: "R60," + xPos + "," + yPos
}, 3000, function() {
    playButtonRef.animate({
        transform: "R0," + xPos + "," + yPos
    }, 3000);
});
playButtonRef.animate(animObject);
```

i have also set up a [working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hE3Jk/) to demonstrate how it's done.