# Rotate image with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to rotate an image with javascript in 90-degree intervals. I have tried a few libraries like [jQuery rotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) and [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html), but they have the same problem - The image is rotated around its center. I have a bunch of content on all sides of the image, and if the image isn't perfectly square, parts of it will end up on top of that content. I want the image to stay inside its parent div, which has max-with and max-height set.

Using jQuery rotate like this (http://jsfiddle.net/s6zSn/1073/):

```
var angle = 0;
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    angle += 90;
    $("#image").rotate(angle);
});
```

Results in this:

[image: How jQuery rotate works]

And this is the result i would like instead:

[image: How I would like it to work]

Anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Use CSS transforms to rotate the entire container around whatever point you like.

Comment: best way to go is using css3 keyframes i'm afraid

Comment: [How to rotate an object back and forth around a specific point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241315/how-to-rotate-an-object-back-and-forth-around-a-specific-point)

Comment: FYI I've explained why this is happening [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301625/rotated-elements-in-css-that-affects-their-parents-height-correctly/16302202#16302202)

Comment: @DiederikEEn I'm afraid too ...

Comment: Question Nicely Asked (by TheQ)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You use a combination of [CSS's `transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) (with vendor prefixes as necessary) and `transform-origin`, like this: [(also on jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/4t8nJ/427/)

```js
var angle = 0,
  img = document.getElementById('container');
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  angle = (angle + 90) % 360;
  img.className = "rotate" + angle;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 820px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container.rotate90,
#container.rotate270 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 820px
}
#image {
  transform-origin: top left;
  /* IE 10+, Firefox, etc. */
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  /* Chrome */
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  /* IE 9 */
}
#container.rotate90 #image {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
}
#container.rotate180 #image {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-100%, -100%);
}
#container.rotate270 #image {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me!</button>
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbLrE.png" id="image" />
</div>
```

Comment: Add `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);` for IE8 and IE7 support. `rotation=1` for 90 deg, `2` for 180 deg, `3` for 270 deg.

Comment: Note that you should really apply this to the image container, if you want the border to work right.

Comment: Nopes ! this transform brings OP to the same problem. The transform is applied but not in the way OP wants

Comment: @OmShankar I think it still gives OP enough to go on.

Comment: This is almost working, however take a look that this: http://jsfiddle.net/bhN6e/. I would like the text below the image to stay below the image, even after rotation. As it is right now, the image ends up on top of the text.

Comment: So [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/bhN6e/1/)? I have added a container around the image, applied the class to the container, adjusted some CSS... Basically, the important thing is to switch the container's width and height around when rotating by 90 or 270.

Comment: @Blazemonger, Look at the **images** in the question asked. OP already has shown in the question that he/she is able to achieve that rotation **already**

Comment: @Kolink: That looks very promising, need to AFK a bit now, but i'll try and implement it on my site tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: **This** is how you answer a question. Nice one.

Answer (score 10):

```
var angle = 0;
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    angle += 90;
    $('#image').css('transform','rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');
});
```

Try this code.

Answer (score 10):

No need for jQuery and lot's of CSS anymore (**Note that some browsers need extra CSS**)

Kind of what @Abinthaha posted, but pure JS, without the need of jQuery.

```js
let rotateAngle = 90;

function rotate(image) {
  image.setAttribute("style", "transform: rotate(" + rotateAngle + "deg)");
  rotateAngle = rotateAngle + 90;
}
```

```css
#rotater {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border: 0.0625em solid black;
  border-radius: 3.75em;
}
```

```html
<img id="rotater" onclick="rotate(this)" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e0/Iron_Man_bleeding_edge.jpg"/>
```

Comment: The original accepted answer still works better for my use case, since I need text to flow properly below the image, and adapt to the size of the image. http://jsfiddle.net/soqkrbut/ is an updated version of the original answer, that works exactly as I want. Using this code does not work, see http://jsfiddle.net/uzhoy6pm/

Comment: Thanks for this; hate when jquery gets forced into a question I otherwise have.

Comment: I know it should be avoided but +1 for the Iron Man image.

Comment: I was ahead of my time (50+ hours in the game now :)

Answer (score 3):

CSS can be applied and you will have to set `transform-origin` correctly to get the applied transformation in the way you want

See the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/OMS_/gkrsz/

**Main code**:

```
/* assuming that the image's height is 70px */

img.rotated {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);

    transform-origin: 35px 35px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 35px 35px;
    -moz-transform-origin: 35px 35px;
    -ms-transform-origin: 35px 35px;
}
```

**jQuery and JS**:

```
$(img)
    .css('transform-origin-x', imgWidth / 2)
    .css('transform-origin-y', imgHeight / 2);

// By calculating the height and width of the image in the load function

// $(img).css('transform-origin', (imgWidth / 2) + ' ' + (imgHeight / 2) );
```

**Logic**:

Divide the image's height by 2. The `transform-x` and `transform-y` values should be this value

**Link**:

**[transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) at CSS | MDN**

Comment: What if the image's size changes, or is just not fixed? That'd be a mess. Mind you, this is a mess with 180 and 270 rotations ;)

Comment: @Kolink. Cool. Anyways, you have jQuery and JS on the page. One can calculate and apply this CSS on the fly. I am editing the answer for JS. Thanks for pointing out !

Comment: Seems a bit over-convoluted. I prefer my solution :p It's completely independent of the image's size.

Comment: @Kolink, I am going per the concept as read from Mozilla DN. In your solution (which is good of course), you are doing an additional tranlate. This is cheating :) Also, conceptually, translating is what is achieved by using the `transform-origin` values - only that they translate the origin of the transform, rather than the element itself

Comment: The problem is that you can't have a single origin to handle all four positions. This is why I stuck with one origin and adjusted the position to place it correctly.

Comment: FYI: If you want to set your `transform-origin` to the centre of the image just use a value of `50%` - e.g.

`transform-origin: 50% 50%;`

Answer (score 3):

i have seen your running code .There is one line correction in your code.

Write:

```
$("#wrapper").rotate(angle);
```

instead of:

```
$("#image").rotate(angle);
```

and you will get your desired output,hope this is what you want.

Comment: @Mikeys4u The library wasn't loading. This one works: http://jsfiddle.net/MQ3YF/112/

Answer (score 3):

Hope this can help you!

```
<input type="button" id="left"  value="left" />
<input type="button" id="right" value="right" />
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="image">

<script>
 var angle = 0;
    $('#left').on('click', function () {  
        angle -= 90;
        $("#image").rotate(angle);
    });

    $('#right').on('click', function () {  
        angle += 90;
        $("#image").rotate(angle);
    });
</script>
```

[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/SabrinaSun/w4fnzra8/)

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work.

```
    document.getElementById('#image').style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
```

Hope this helps. It's work with me.

Answer (score 2):

You can always apply CCS class with `rotate` property - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/

To keep rotated image within your `div` dimensions you need to adjust CSS as well, there is no needs to use JavaScript except of adding class.

Comment: "CCS class with rotate property" - Both typo and conceptual error?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Anuga](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51817813/9938317) answer I have extended it to multiple images.

Keep track of the rotation angle of the image as an attribute of the image.

```js
function rotate(image) {
  let rotateAngle = Number(image.getAttribute("rotangle")) + 90;
  image.setAttribute("style", "transform: rotate(" + rotateAngle + "deg)");
  image.setAttribute("rotangle", "" + rotateAngle);
}
```

```css
.rotater {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border: 0.0625em solid black;
  border-radius: 3.75em;
}
```

```html
<img class="rotater" onclick="rotate(this)" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e0/Iron_Man_bleeding_edge.jpg"/>
<img class="rotater" onclick="rotate(this)" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e0/Iron_Man_bleeding_edge.jpg"/>
<img class="rotater" onclick="rotate(this)" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e0/Iron_Man_bleeding_edge.jpg"/>
```

**Edit**

Removed the modulo, looks strange.