# Rotating an image made in javascript

Tags: javascript, image-rotation

I want to rotate an image IN javascript. The variable used for the image in javascript is heroImage. I am using jquery rotate, it works fine only when rotating images in html, but not in javascript. Normally it looks something like this

```
$("#image").rotate(angle);
```

But that only works for images created in html.

This is part of the code im currently using

```
var heroImage = new Image();
heroImage.src = "images/hero.png";
```

and its drawn of canvas , if that helps. the problem is #image can only refer to a html div element afaik..
The answer that im not looking for is this:

```
$("#image").rotate(angle);
```

Because that only works for html images

Its for a game, so everything has to be in javascript , anything css related doesnt seem to work.
It also  has to be IE9 compatible

Comment: Just draw it [in a rotated context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#rotate())?

Comment: Thanks, I learned alot from that link!

Comment: That will rotate everything, not a specific object.

Comment: Not when you reset the transformation to draw the other things…

Answer (score 1):

You can draw it on canvas and then rotate scene in canvas

```
ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 4);
```

or, rotate whole canvas using CSS3 transforms

```
document.getElementById('#canvas').style.webkitTransform = "rotate(45deg)";
```

Comment: ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 4);

Comment: will rotate EVERYTHING. not just a single image/object

Comment: @none: You just need to use a different transformation to draw the other things then

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 for this job.

```
img.rotated {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

As an example you can look into FontAwesome's CSS

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#rotated-flipped

If you **have** to use javascript, use can change CSS via JS.

```
document.getElementById('img.rotated').style.transform = rotate(30deg);
```

Comment: doesnt document.getElementById('img.rotated') refer to a html division?

Comment: It modifies CSS style of DOM Tree using JS. HTML is just a way to define DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add 'id' property to image

```
heroImage.id = 'image';
```

and add css for the 'image' as follows

```
$('#image').css('transform', 'rotate('+angle+'deg)');
```

[here is detailed discussion on acheieving this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794310/rotate-image-with-javascript)

Comment: Thats interesting, ill take a look at it.

Comment: javascript:heroImage.id = 'image';
 heroImage.angle = 45; and I added the css like you said, but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: here it is. 
if write heroImage.id ='image'; heroImage.src='images/hero.png' it will be converted to <img id='image' src='image/hero.png' /> since img doesnot have any valid attribute called angle it doesnot work.
essential by adding css like following $('#image').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)'); it appends to the <img> as <img id='image' src='image/hero.png' style='-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg)'>
In this example value of angle is hardcoded. To make it dynamic use the code this $('#image').css('transform', 'rotate('+angle+'deg)'); where 'angle' is a variable.