# How to solve picture orientation after upload PHP without using exif_read_data()

Tags: php, exif

exif_read_data() is not working with my server.
I have tried with changing the order of these lines and restarted my apache,

> 1   extension=php_exif.dll
>
> 2   extension=php_mbstring.dll

and contacted the server provider and they say that they have enabled the exif extension but the function is not working for me.

I have also tried with printing the `phpinfo()` but it contains nothing related to exif.

So is there any alternative to read the orientation and rerotate the image?

Or can we do something to prevent the rotation of the image during upload

Thanks

Comment: Use a [Javascript solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794310/rotate-image-with-javascript). Use a [third-party solution](https://www.imgix.com/).  Fix your server (was the web server restarted)?  From the command line, if you have that SAPI installed, try: `php -r 'phpinfo();' | more`

Comment: The php_mbstring.dll DLL must be loaded before the php_exif.dll DLL so adjust your php.ini accordingly.

Comment: @moskito-x they are loading in this order
;;extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll

Comment: @Jobz : Can you tell how this fit together. `I have tried with changing the order of these lines and restarted my apache` versus `contacted the server provider and they say that they have enabled the exif extension`. Once to ask the provider to enable `exif` and then restart the server yourself?