# Rotate and unrotate an image onClick with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to find how to make an image rotate 90 degrees to the right on the first click, and when clicked again, return to it's original orientation.
I was looking at this question made by another person on stack overflow, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794310/rotate-image-with-javascript) didn't include the image rotating back when it was clicked again.

So far, CSS has shown potential, but I cannot seem to get the image rotated back on the second click.

This is the image if you need a reference:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAY0q.png)

Here is my script:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .rotate {
               -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
                 transform: rotate(90deg);
            }

            .normal {
               -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                 transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
        </style>

        <script>
        function Rotate() {
            var rotate = 0
            var rotate = rotate + 1

            if (rotate = 2) {
                document.getElementbyID(image).className = 'normal';
            }
            else if (rotate <= 3) {
                var rotate = 0
                location.reload();
            }
            else {
                document.getElementbyID(image).className = 'rotate';
            }
        }
        </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAY0q.png" alt="image" onclick="Rotate()" class="normal" id="image"/>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794310/rotate-image-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet running what you ar trying to achieve:

```js
function Rotate() {
  var element = document.getElementById('image');

  if (element.className === "normal") {
   element.className = "rotate";
  }
  else if ( element.className === "rotate") {
   element.className = 'normal';
  }
 }
```

```css
.rotate {
   -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
     transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.normal {
   -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
     transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAY0q.png" alt="image" onclick="Rotate()" class="normal" id="image"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind that you had several syntax errors on your code such as: document.getElementById() and using a single = for comparison.

You can check you browser console for checking erros like those.

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors in your script first: you redeclare rotate in many parts of script, second : within if you must compare with `==` and not `=`, this last is to assign a value, third: is `getElementById` not `getElementbyID`

Try with this script:

```
<script>
    var rotate = false;

    function Rotate() {

        if (rotate == true) {
            document.getElementById('image').className = 'normal';
            rotate = false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('image').className = 'rotate';
            rotate = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestions made by Jose Rojas, I have found a way to reset orientation by modifying some script on a page suggested by this site. You can view it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794310/rotate-image-with-javascript). I will modify the CSS scripts for every other angle, so the process can last forever.