# Rotating individual graphics images in javasctipt

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics

I'm trying to rotate a graphic from an image in javascript and so far I have not had much luck.  I tried creating a separate canvas to do this but this has resulted in distorted images that seem to appear and disappear on the canvas.  This is the function that I'm using right now:

```
function rotImage(img,deg){
    var rotateImage;
    var radDegrees = deg * (Math.PI/180);
    var imageRotCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var imageRotCanvasCtx = imageRotCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var rotWidth = Math.ceil(Math.abs((img.width * Math.cos(radDegrees)) + (img.height * Math.sin(radDegrees))));
    var rotHeight = Math.ceil(Math.abs((-img.width * Math.sin(radDegrees)) + (img.height * Math.cos(radDegrees))));
    imageRotCanvas.width = rotWidth*8;
    imageRotCanvas.height = rotHeight*8;
    imageRotCanvasCtx.rotate(radDegrees);
    imageRotCanvasCtx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    rotateImage = imageRotCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    return rotateImage;
}
```

Is there a better way to do basic manipulation of 2d graphics?  I'm learning Javascript for fun and so far GFX have been by biggest problem.  If there's a library or something I'd be happy to use that.  This is for a series of objects and not a single image.  I'm going to have multiple images that will have to be rotated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate image with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794310/rotate-image-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  Looks as though there really isn't a good way of doing this, save with an external source.  I'll mark it as answered.