# Angular animation : Rotation 180° click image

Tags: html, angular, angular-animations

How to make a image rotation (click : 0° -> 180° / click again : 180° -> 0°) on image button with Angular 4 ?

I use Angular Material too.

This is my button :

```
 <!-- Button open left menubar -->
<button md-icon-button class="left-menubar-button"  (click)="start.toggle()">
  <md-icon class="md-custom-theme-gray">label_outline</md-icon>
</button>
```

This button will open a sidenav, and I want to animate it to get more userfriendly

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You do not need material as Angular brings built in animations.  Here goes an example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
      // Each unique animation requires its own trigger. The first argument of the trigger function is the name
      trigger('rotatedState', [
        state('default', style({ transform: 'rotate(0)' })),
        state('rotated', style({ transform: 'rotate(-180deg)' })),
        transition('rotated => default', animate('1500ms ease-out')),
        transition('default => rotated', animate('400ms ease-in'))
      ])
  ]
})

export class AppComponent {
    state: string = 'default';
    rotate() {
        this.state = (this.state === 'default' ? 'rotated' : 'default');
    }
}
```

And in template:

```
<button (click)="rotate()">Press me to rotate</button>
```

And make sure to add binding to tag you are operating on:

```
<img [@rotatedState]='state' />
```

In addition make sure you import the animation module to your app like so:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
    ...,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

Check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-image-rotation) with working example

Comment: is it possible to rotate image 4 sides? can you please show me how to do that.

Comment: u mean do a full rotation so that the image ends at starting position?

Comment: simply change rotate(-180deg) to rotate(-360deg)     . That will do a full rotation. If this answer helped you out please upvote :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but user can rotate unsteady images that we need about 4 states (90,180,270,360deg) something similar like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794310/rotate-image-with-javascript

Comment: How to save rotated image?