# Rotate an image with css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Today I thought about creating a different button... So I thought: if I get an image that rotates 180 degrees when I click it and rotates more 180 degrees again and again again... (every time I click). After lots of tries, I don't know how can I do it. This was what I thought and made:

**HTML:**

`<img id="rotater" onclick="rotate()" src="anyImage.png"/>`

**CSS:**

```
img{border: 0.0625em solid black;border-radius: 3.75em;}
#rotate{ animation: rotation 3s 0.5 forwards;}
@keyframes rotation{50% {transform: rotate(180deg);}}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function rotate(){x=document.getElementById('rotater');x.id = 'rotate';}
```

It's not important, just an idea...

Comment: for the fun and via attribute `tabindex` and CSS (`:focus/pointer-events`) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VBRzdP (no javascript being harmed here ;) )

Comment: I need to get the element rotation degrees, cause if i apply this for more than one image... It wont work good.

Comment: @Jackjoss: I have modified Anuga's answer for multiple images https://stackoverflow.com/a/51879318/9938317

Answer (score 2):

Try this

With this code, your image will rotate 180deg each, everytime you click the image

```js
let rotateAngle = 180;
function rotate() {
  $("#rotater").css({'transform': 'rotate('+rotateAngle+'deg)'});
  rotateAngle = rotateAngle + 180;
}
```

```css
#rotater {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border: 0.0625em solid black;
  border-radius: 3.75em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="rotater" onclick="rotate()" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e0/Iron_Man_bleeding_edge.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Why add jQuery? not necessary.

Comment: Added `jQuery` so that I can use like `$("#rotater")`. It's possible without using jQuery as well.

Comment: Yea, one really don't need to get the element by the ID in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of what @Abinthaha posted, but pure JS, without the need of jQuery.

```js
let rotateAngle = 180;

function rotate(image) {
  image.setAttribute("style", "transform: rotate(" + rotateAngle + "deg)");
  rotateAngle = rotateAngle + 180;
}
```

```css
#rotater {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border: 0.0625em solid black;
  border-radius: 3.75em;
}
```

```html
<img id="rotater" onclick="rotate(this)" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e0/Iron_Man_bleeding_edge.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

For rotating image by 180 degree using jquery use this 
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="rotater" onclick="rotate();"  src="anyImage.png"/>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let rotateAngle = 180;
    function rotate(){
        $("#rotater").css({'transform': 'rotate('+rotateAngle+'deg)'});
        rotateAngle = rotateAngle + 180;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

`

Comment: This will work only one time. I guess @Jackjoss wants to rotate the image 180 everytime he clicks it.

Comment: Why add jQuery? not necessary.